# Import Images in Module Through Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, import, ecmascript-6

I am using NodeJs, webpack & ES2015 for my app.

I cannot seem to figure out how to import an image/s in my modules.
The following does not work.

```
import "../../css/image/t1.png";
```

EDIT:
As per Sitian's request, here is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require( "webpack" );
const path = require( "path" );
const merge = require( "webpack-merge" );
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;

const PATHS = {
    app : path.join( __dirname, "app" ),
    build : path.join( __dirname, "build" )
};

const common = {
    entry : {
        app : PATHS.app
    },
    resolve : { // helps us refer to .js? without ext.
        extensions : [ "", ".js", ".jsx" ]
    },
    output : {
        path : PATHS.build,
        filename : "bundle.js"
    },
    module : {
        preLoaders : [
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                loaders : [ "postcss" ],
                include : PATHS.app
            },
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders : [ "eslint" ],
                include : PATHS.app
            }
        ],
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                loaders : [ "style", "css" ],
                include : PATHS.app
            },
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : 'babel',
                query : {
                    cacheDirectory : true,
                    presets : [ 'react', 'es2015' ]
                },
                include : PATHS.app
            }
        ]
    }
};

if( TARGET === "start" || !TARGET ) {
    module.exports = merge( common, {
        devtool : 'inline-source-map',
        devServer : {
            contentBase : PATHS.build,
            hot : true,
            progress : true,
            stats : 'errors-only'
        },
        plugins : [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        ]
    } );
}
if( TARGET === "build" ) {
  module.exports = merge( common, {} );
}
```

Comment: I believe that imports must be linked to a function, object, or primitive that has been exported from somewhere else. So, unless you are using some abstraction of import that I am not aware of (and is in no way related to ES6 imports), this code will never work.

Comment: @Kayote could you paste your webpack config here? I would be happy to show you the way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) (or [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader), which "*can return a Data Url if the file is smaller than a limit*") can be used to import images into modules.

See the [webpack loaders documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) for more information on how to use such loaders:

> ### Configuration
>
> ```
> { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }
> ```

Comment: but what if I just want to use images? I thought `import` was needed to make sure the images get placed into the `dist` folder. Or do I have to do that manually?

Comment: The loader will make sure the referenced images are part of the bundle, and it will copy them to your `dist` folder. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

With current versions of webpack it should work:

```
import t1 from "../../css/image/t1.png";
```

and your webpack.config (webpack 2.0):

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {test: /\.png$/, use: 'url-loader?mimetype=image/png'},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a loader to your webpack (v1) configuration:

```
 {
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" 
 }
```

then install it:

```
npm install url-loader
```

and finally you are going to be able to import the image by using:

```
import image from 'images/name.png'
```

Comment: I keep getting `Cannot find module '../assets/image.png', regardless of what path I provide.

Comment: The code above defines `image` as a variable containing the url of the image. In your jsx you need to set the image source using curly braces like this `<img src={image} />`