# how to import a picture in the same directory

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import image from './picture.jpg';

export class NavBar extends React.Component {
    render() {

    return (
        <img  src = {image}/>
    )
}
```

}

```
ERROR in ./dev/js/picture.jpg
Module parse failed: D:\App\Webstrome\programs\Project1\dev\js\picture.jpg   Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

I am trying to import a picture which is in the same directory, but I got the above error. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Images in Module Through Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195565/import-images-in-module-through-webpack)

Comment: Correct, it looks like there's no loader configured. See the link of @MayankShukla.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import an image file, it will load over HTTP in the browser:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <img  src="/picture.jpg" />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I tried it, but it still showed the same error.

Comment: Disregard. Once more - you don't need to import an image into js code. If the error is the same - the import is still there. Remove the `import image from './picture.jpg';` line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to import the image to your file before calling it you need to configure your loader as previously mentioned with something like this In your webpack config file:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(jpg)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
```

And then install:

```
npm install file-loader
```

or

```
yarn add file-loader
```

You could also try exporting your image before importing it. This is generally only used for images in a directory separate from your components.  In a separate js file located in the same directory as your image:

```
export picture from './picture.jpg';
```

Refer to these links for more:

http://interglobalmedianetwork.com/post/importing-images-in-react/

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/